# trying to add the sum of random ints in a temporary array and have the highest sum be output

Tags: java

my program is a kind of game. It gives the user 3 boards(arrays) of random ints and has them choose which board they think has the highest sum of numbers all within a time limit. I cant figure out how to add the sums of the individual arrays by using a temp array. I'm honestly just really stuck and don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Ive been at this for hours.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class game
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Holds a local scanner 
    private static int secondsLeft; // Number of seconds after each turn
    private static int score = 0;   // Score variable which you update
    private static NonBlockingHasNext t = new NonBlockingHasNext(); // Special class for timer
    private static int [][][] gameBoard = new int [3][3][3]; // TODO 2: Initialize to a new 3x3x3 array
    //static int row = 0;
    //static int column = 0;
    //static int depth = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {



        // Give user instructions and begin
        System.out.println("You will be presented 3 3x3 boards of random numbers, labeled 1, 2 and 3.");
        System.out.println("Quickly select the board you believe to contain the largest sum of 9 numbers" +
                " by entering the board number and pressing enter");
        System.out.println("Press any key and hit enter to begin...");
        scan.nextLine();

        int numTurns = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < numTurns; i++)
        {
            reInit3dBoard();
            print3dBoard(i, numTurns);
            int choiceMade = countDownTimer();
            choiceMade--; // Decrement to match with 0-indexed arrays   
            analyzeChoice(choiceMade);          
        }           
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // countDownTimer() counts down from 10 seconds. Returns
    // the user input if the value that is input is a 1, 2
    // or 3. If the value is something else or no value is
    // input, this method returns a -1.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static int countDownTimer()
    {
        // Some really complicated stuff to work around Java shortcomings.
        // Basically, this code creates a new "thread" which allows us to
        // run other code while a scanner in NonBlockingHasNext is waiting
        // for a user input.
        t = new NonBlockingHasNext();
        (new Thread(t)).start();

        System.out.println("Seconds left to make choice: ");
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            secondsLeft = i;
            System.out.print(secondsLeft + "...");


            // Sleep for 1 second and....
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); }


            // ...check again for input. If received a valid input in time, then return it
            if (t.hasNext())
            {
                // Make sure choice is valid (1, 2 or 3)
                int choice = t.nextInt(); //scan.nextInt();
                if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nYou chose grid #" + choice + " with " + secondsLeft + " seconds left!");
                    return choice;
                }               
            }
        }

        // If we get here, then no choice was made!
        System.out.println("\nNo choice made!");
        return -1; // If no valid choice made
    }




    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Simply assigns each element of the 3x3x3 3D board
    // a random number from 1-9 (should not see 0's or 10's)
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static void reInit3dBoard(){
        Random rand = new Random();


        {
            for(int row=0;row<gameBoard.length; ++row){

                for(int column=0;column<gameBoard[row].length; ++column){

                    for(int depth=0;depth<gameBoard[row][column].length; ++depth )
                        gameBoard[row][column][depth]=rand.nextInt(9)+1;



                }

            }





        }     
    }
    // TODO 3: Generate a random assignment of the gameBoard variable
    // (see member variables) as described in the method header above.
    // NOTE: You can just overwrite the values there.


    private static int[][] randomFill() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Prints the 3x3x3 3D board out to the console. It
    // should print 3 2d boards. The line directly above each board
    // should be labeled "Board 1:", "Board 2:" or "Board 3:".
    // The line directly below each board should be blank. 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static void print3dBoard(int turn, int numTurns)
    {
        System.out.println("--------------------------Turn " + (turn+1) + "/" + numTurns + "--------------------------");
        for(int row=0; row<gameBoard.length; ++row)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nboard:"+ row);
            //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(gameBoard));


            for(int column=0; column<gameBoard.length; ++column)
            {System.out.println();




            for(int depth=0; depth<gameBoard.length; ++depth)
            {System.out.print(gameBoard[row][column][depth]);

            }
            }           
        }
    }       



    // TODO 4: Print out the 3d board as described in the method header above.
    // Make sure to label the boards 1-3 and not 0-2.


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // This method analyzes the choice made by the user 
    // conveniently passed into us for array-indexing purposes
    // as a 0, 1 or 2.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static void analyzeChoice(int choiceMade)
    {





        // TODO 5: Create a counter array and use several FOR loops
        // to compute the sum of each of the 3 boards.
        int temp [][][] = new int [3][3][3];
        temp = gameBoard;
        int sum = 0;







        // TODO 6: From your counter array, compute the max score


        // TODO 7: Print out the score of all three boards (e.g., "Board 1 value: 34"). Number
        // the boards 1-3 b/c this is what the user saw when selecting.
        // Next to the selected board, add the string "(Right)" or "(Wrong)" if their guess
        // was correct (i.e., the max board). Also, update the score by adding the number
        // of seconds left when the guess was made.

        // HINT: At this point, the member variable "score" holds the current score and the
        // member variable "secondsLeft" holds the seconds left when the last selection was made.

        // Print out the current score
        System.out.println("\n***Current Score: " + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for NonBlockingHasNext ?

Comment: it is in a separate file that is complete. Shouldve mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Just think of each board as 27 different variables. For example: 

`int space1 =gameBoard[1][1][1]
int space2 =gameBoard[1][1][2]`

.
.
.
.
.

`int space27 =gameBoard[3][3][3]`

Then just add up spaces 1-27

This would be much easier than using a temporary array

If you want, you can store the sum of each board in its own array afterwords:

```
score1=space1+space2+space3...
    int scores[3];
    scores[1]=score1;
```

etc.

Edit: If you HAVE to use a temporary array just do it like this:

```
int score[3];
score[1]=gameBoard[1][1][1]+gameBoard[1][1][2]+gameBoard[1][1][3] ...
```

And skip the middleman

Comment: I would do that but I have to use a temp array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add another function which will count sum of array of type 3x3:

```
public static int countSum(int[][] arr) {
    if(arr == null) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) {
        int[] arr1 = arr[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            sum+=arr1[j];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

and rewrite your analyzeChoice method:

```
private static void analyzeChoice(int choiceMade)
{
    int temp [][][] = new int [3][3][3];
    temp = gameBoard;

    int[] sums = new int[]{0, 0, 0}; /*sums for each table*/
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        int[][] inner_arr = temp[i];
        sums[i] = countSum(inner_arr);
    }

    int maxsum = 0;
    int maxint = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
        if(sums[i] > maxsum) {
            maxsum = sums[i]; maxint = i;
        }
    }

    if(maxint == choiceMade) {
        score++;
    }

    // Print out the current score
    System.out.println("\n***Current Score: " + score);
}
```